# Error: NoClassDefFoundError When Using Eclipse To Run COMSOL Model

Tags: java, eclipse, api, comsol

I am trying to use Eclipse to run a COMSOL model and I have read the guide from programming reference manual. However, Eclipse always report the error as follows,

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter at com.comsol.client.interfaces.b.(SourceFile:60) at com.comsol.client.interfaces.b.(SourceFile:39) at com.comsol.clientapi.engine.APIEngine$c.b(SourceFile:497) at com.comsol.clientapi.engine.APIEngine.a(SourceFile:115) at com.comsol.clientapi.engine.APIEngine.connect(SourceFile:98) at com.comsol.clientapi.engine.APIEngine.connect(SourceFile:87) at com.comsol.clientapi.engine.ClientModelUtil.connect(SourceFile:145) at com.comsol.clientapi.engine.ClientModelUtil.connect(SourceFile:133) at com.comsol.model.util.ModelUtil.connect(SourceFile:248) at PFCZM_3PBending_QuasiBrittle.main(PFCZM_3PBending_QuasiBrittle.java:16750) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ... 10 more

I believe I have imported the JAR files correctly and set the path for the project and it seems that the error is due to lack of source file for COMSOL API JAR files. I have checked those JAR file and found they are indeed all class files without definition. How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with source files. It can't find `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` - javax.xml.bind used to be included with Java but now needs to be downloaded separately - see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43574426/2670892)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and it works. Thank you very much!